# How to automate fast mouse drag in Python?

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyautogui

I've tried to automate mouse drag with [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) by launching this code:

```
 pyautogui.dragTo(1900, 500, 0.1, button='left')
```

But instead of performing it with 0.1 seconds it takes much longer. How to automate mouse drag with high velocity? Maybe fix something with pyautogui or anyone knows another lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the code, and it seems instantaneous, you might try `pyautogui.dragTo(1900, 500, 0, button='left')`

Answer (score 0):

So I found the only one solution - HumanClicker, it's not that smooth